Where are older Xcode versions located on developer.apple.com?
Why are older Xcode versions are impossible to find on developer.apple.com?
Xcode 15.2 15C500b specifically is nowhere to be found in the apple.com domain.
Why are they making developer's lives difficult?
There used to be a link "older downloads" in there.

Did you try https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode ?

I keep many of the installer files even when I update to a later version. Make sit easier to go back one or two...

Well, I keep older versions renamed in the /Applications this is just a new mac. Thanks nohillside - that should be accepted answer

It's mentioned on the question I closed yours as a dupe of, several times
